# Arduino Based Solid State Drive

Tags: system-design

I've searched high and low for something to get me on the right track, it's making me think it might not be possible.

Basically, I want to create a cheap SSD using Arduino (or another microcontroller if it is too weak). I know I would have to implement the SATA protocol on the device and an OS driver for the disk drive. Assuming I could jump those two hurdles, what else would bar me from implementing a rudimentary SSD? I'm not even talking about full production quality, just a SATA wire coming from a mother board plugged into a socket on a breadboard. Do I need flash storage or would I need another kind of chip to handle the data needs?

Comment: Do you understand what SSD is standing for? Maybe you mean just **some kind** of SATA-connected storage?

Comment: The legacy SATA 1.0 throughput of 1.5 GB/s is going to be a *huge* problem without dedicated hardware - I don't think you stand a chance on any Arduino.

Comment: Is the SATA standard really not documented anywhere on the entire internet?

Comment: If you want to do this just for fun, implement USB Mass Storage on a Leonardo backed by an SD card or SPI flash.  It will be painfully slow, but the concept will be there.  Outside of the Arduino realm, I expect you could find an existing project to do this with the STM32F4 Discovery board (which is cheaper anyway).

Comment: This is such an awesome quest, Creating a storage device from scratch to be used from a computer. I really hope you succeed and please post updates if you make it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The good news is that SATA drivers are fairly generic so you don't have to write the OS side. The bad news is everything else.

*just a SATA wire coming from a mother board plugged into a socket on a breadboard*

Let me stop you there. The minimum data rate for SATA is sufficiently high that you need a PCB. If you try and do this with wires or breadboards it will simply not get through; it will be lost to parasitic capacitance.

(Many years ago as a student I tried to do something vaguely similar with a wire-wrap board. At just 20MHz you could see a clean signal go in one side and a noisy unreadable mess come out the other side. Actually seeing it on a scope drove home the importance of shielding.)

*Do I need flash storage or would I need another kind of chip to handle the data needs*

Where would you put the data otherwise? It might be an entertaining first step to create a read-only drive with constant contents, but it's not very useful.

You need a chip with a SATA interface. This will almost certainly be an ARM and almost certainly *not* in DIP. I can't remember at the moment whether SATA master and slave "PHY" interfaces are different or whether it's all defined in software, someone else can answer that.

Comment: Sweet thanks for the info. I guess the Arduino is a very "beginner's" setup so I would want to get a more advanced controller for such an undertaking. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @pjc50 - He could implement a Write Only Memory - perhaps an emulation of the [**Signetics 9C46XN / 25120**](http://repeater-builder.com/molotora/gontor/25120-bw.pdf)